# How to invoke a ViewComponent in ViewComponent in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, invoke

I am trying to draw a webpage from database (CMS). So i created a few ViewComponents for this. Here is some ViewComponents

DrawPage,DrawRow,DrawColumn
When i tried to call rows inside a foreach it is working bu showing nothing. For example

```
foreach(var item in Rows)
{
await Component.InvokeAsync("DrawRow", item);
}
```

Then in DrawRow ViewComponent

```
foreach(var item in Columns)
{
await Component.InvokeAsync("DrawColumn", item);
}
```

i can find breakpoints in DrawRow component and i can see data in code side. But when i see the page there is nothing. I think the problem can be from calling async in async

Comment: Share us demo project to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Where can i share a .net core demo project?

Comment: You could upload it to Github and share us link here.